# using sparse models to accelerate training

Tags: machine-learning, sparse

I was going through a tutorial that highlights the importance of using sparse models to get "lightning fast models" i.e. to accelerate the training process.

What are the issues in using a sparse model? How will it affect the performance of the resultant model as against a non-sparse model.

Are there any limitations to using a sparse model ?

Comment: Sparse models can be more difficult to train (slower convergence). The book by Tibshirani & Hastie "Statistical Learning with Sparsity" is a pretty recent book on the subject. It is fairly accessible and has many gems!

Comment: What do you exactly mean by sparse ? Usually, they are not faster to train than there dense counterpart (a LASSO regression will be longer to train than a regular one). Or do you think about sparse representation of the data, in case of high dimensionality (where a lot of components are 0) ? (which indeed makes training much faster...)